# Generate a SQL script that populate specified test data for employees

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, insert

Write a script to populate test data for employees. It should be possible for the script to populate the specified number of employees. The test data populated with the script should be imaginary but systematically correct.

By using SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment

Comment: Yes it is a homework assignment

Answer (score 0):

Populate name test data example: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2181/populating-a-sql-server-test-database-with-random-data/

Also here: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468159/how-can-i-insert-random-values-into-a-sql-server-table)